# How do you hit the enemies from below?

Tags: once-upon-a-tower

I can't complete the challenge because I don't know how to hit the enemies that are above you. What do I have to do to be able to hit them?

[image: challenge 9]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to hit enemies from below was to get the fire hammer, then jump past the red dogs and let them run down onto you, while shooting up with the fire  hammer.